# What are the values of the absolute intracellular and absolute extracellular potentials in a neuron?

Tags: neuroscience, measurement, theoretical-neuroscience, neurophysiology, neural-network

Most texts on neurons give the value of the membrane potential and do not state the absolute values of the intracellular and extracellular potentials in a neuron. I understand that this is because the membrane potential is all that is needed to understand propagation of impulses along a neuron. However, I am curious about the absolute intracellular and extracellular potentials in a resting neuron. Have they been determined? If yes, what are their values if we take our reference of zero potential as a point infinitely far away from the neuron?

Comment: Why care? It's completely irrelevant to any biology.

Comment: That doesn't stop it from being a completely valid question.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" from https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask